# Android Eclipse: Why can't I import full project from github !!! (Caldroid)

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I want to import caldroid from github into my workspace but it does not work. As you can see the "library" is grayed out and when I click the box it colors it instead of a check mark.

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

You should have figured it out by now.

Anyways,
The library is still being imported. In this, the blue box determines that you have options available while importing the library. i.e to import or not to import anything under it.The 'demo' uses the 'library' and as you are importing 'demo' the 'library' has to be imported as it has a dependency on it.